# Why is the Dirac QFT Spin Operator depending on the state?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

I am reading the book *Student friendly quantum field theory* , I feel sorry to paste the entire page, but I just want to illustrate this more clear. This very a long page. Firstly the author defined the QFT spin operator in (4-110), and then he checked the result of this operator functions on a state to gain the desired value 1/2 in (4-116). During this process he seemed to used the fact that the operator should depend on the state being measured at *the third term after the second equal sign in (4-116)*. This, I don't understand. How can a measurement be affected by the thing been observed?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If I understood you correctly - this is a well-known technique to derive the properties of an operator: you act with it on an arbitrary state and see what becomes with the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dirac operator is $ -i\not D $ , but it seems the author has called the Dirac hamiltonian the dirac operator. In QFT we make the local Hamiltonian out of quantum fields in order to ensure locality. The Hamiltonian operator is then an integral of a local hamiltonian densiy over all space-time. If you get the dirac equation and ask for what lagragian gives it and then from that construct the Hamiltonian you will get something like what the author calls the Dirac operator.

Comment: But if this is so then the author used the this in (4-116). It seemed that he used it to function on one state for two times?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the equation $$\text{QFT}\Sigma _i=\int _V\psi ^{\dagger }\Sigma _i\psi~\mathrm d^3x$$
seems to say that $\text{QFT}\Sigma_i$ depends on the state $\psi$? Then I think your confusion comes from that in QFT, $\psi$ isn't a state, it's a field, and fields are operators.

Comment: @ Robin Ekman   Hello, I have pasted a very long page in the question so that you may take a closer look what i am confusing about. I know this is a bit  plum.